# SQL/Oracle: How to find the key of the 'N' occurrence for EACH value?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Lets say a table like this (just for illustration):

```
KEY  VALUE
  1      A
  2      A    
  3      B
  4      C
  5      A
  6      B
  7      C
  8      A
  9      C
```

I need a **SINGLE SQL** to get the key of the 3th (or less) occurrence for EACH value?

```
VALUE  KEY 
    A    5    (more than 3 occurrences, so it gets the 3th occurrence)  
    B    6    (only 2 occurrences, so it gets the last one)
    C    9
```

**Update: Oracle 10g**

Comment: 3td occurrence has a meaning only if you specify an order (there is no guaranteed order when you select rows from a table for relational databases.) Is the order KEY ASC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is a simpler way to write this without needing 3 layers of nesting.  But this should work.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 1 key, 'A' val from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'A' from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'B' from dual union all
  5    select 4, 'C' from dual union all
  6    select 5, 'A' from dual union all
  7    select 6, 'B' from dual union all
  8    select 7, 'C' from dual union all
  9    select 8, 'A' from dual union all
 10    select 9, 'C' from dual)
 11  select key,
 12         val
 13    from (select key,
 14                 val,
 15                 rnk,
 16                 max(rnk) over (partition by val) max_rnk
 17            from (select key,
 18                         val,
 19                         rank() over (partition by val order by key) rnk
 20                    from x
 21                 )
 22           where rnk <= 3
 23         )
 24*  where rnk = max_rnk
SQL> /

       KEY V
---------- -
         5 A
         6 B
         9 C
```

Comment: So Elegant! Thank you Justin. That's exactly I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Value, t1."KEY"
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY "KEY") AS RowNumber, 
             "KEY", Value
      FROM MyTable) t1
     LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY "KEY") AS RowNumber,
             "KEY", Value
      FROM MyTable) t2 ON t2.Value = t1.Value AND t2.RowNumber = t1.RowNumber + 1
WHERE t1.RowNumber = 3 OR (t1.RowNumber IN (1, 2) AND t2."Key" IS NULL)
```

Comment: That's not valid SQL - at least not for Oracle (`[Key]` is an invalid identifier in standard SQL and Oracle)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am just matching his sample data, he is gonna have to replace the [Key] with whatever actual column name he has!

Comment: The correct way would be `"KEY"` as the double quotes will make it case-sensitive. But `KEY` is not a reserved word anyway in Oracle so it does not require quoting.